# Extract a number from alphanumeric string using R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, extract

I am new in R, I have a data frame:

```
   Var       measurement  
1 SEDA2015     0.258
2 SEDA2015     0.156
3 SEDA2015     0.04

456 SEDA2018   0.523
```

So I need to Separate "Var" into new variable. I try the Separate and extract from Reard
Someone Could helpme,
Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: " I try the Separate and extract from Reard" What's Reard?